# can i set asymmetric memories without losing speed?

Tags: memory

I have an old PC with two DIMMs, each 4GB. I don't know what type (DDR3/DDR4) or frequency those modules are. I'm building a new PC with two DDR4 DIMMs, each 8GB and 3200MHz. Is it possible for me to use my old memory in my new PC without losing speed? If so, how should I configure it?

- Ch1 (8GB+8GB) and Ch2 (4GB+4GB)
- Ch1 (8GB+4GB) and Ch2 (8GB+4GB)

Or should I do it some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the old PC memories are DDR4, then chances are they have a lower frequency than 3200mhz. You are automatically going to **lose speed** with the old ones.

As for physical compatibility: refer to this chart:
[image]

If the key isn't at the same place (It's DDR3 instead of DDR4) then ***do not*** install them in your new system. They cannot fit physically and forcing it in will break something.